# 'AuthenticationHelper' does not contain a definition for 'AuthenticateUser'

Tags: .net-core, kentico-13

We are currently in an upgrade to Kentico 13 from Kentico 12 and running into a smallish problem.

We have an enrollment page that sends its data to a .net core api (using .net 7.0)  I have gotten the Kentico Libaries from NUGIT and they are the same as the version we have installed for the upgrade.

When the user compleats the enrollment a full user profile is created and has all the correct values that can beuse from the sign in page,  however we are not able to set the user to be authenticated due to this: 'AuthenticationHelper' does not contain a definition for 'AuthenticateUser'

All current documentation shows that Authenticate user should be there.  Any ideas?  I am sure if it was there I would have no need to write this post.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading to .NET Core, the Kentico.Xperience.Libraries is using a different CMS.Membership.dll:

- .NET Framework: `Kentico.Xperience.Libraries.13.0.xxx\lib\net48\CMS.Membership.dll`
- .NET Core 6: `kentico.xperience.libraries\13.0.xxx\lib\net6.0\CMS.Membership.xml`

So that's why the `AuthentiationHelper.AuthenticateUser()` isn't available anymore. You'll have to use a different way.

You could make use of the SignInManager, read here more: https://docs.xperience.io/managing-users/user-registration-and-authentication/integrating-xperience-membership

```
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

public MyClass(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager) 
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
}

...

var userInfo = UserInfo.Provider.Get(username);
var signInResult = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(new ApplicationUser(userInfo), password, false);

if (signInResult.Succeeded) 
{
    //is authenticated
}
```